# I want to map from a string with values to 2 lists

Tags: python, string

I have a giant multi-line string that's built like

```
'''
"key0": "value0",
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
'''
```

I would like to turn this into 2 lists: one for all the keys and one for all the values.

There is no way to receive this data in any way other than a string.

The list should be ordered the same. Running `print(keys[0])` should return the string `"key0"`.

How do I do this? I'm new to Python

Comment: Can you confirm if this is JSON?  If yes, read the file with the built it `json` library, which reads as a Python dict.  Then extracting the keys and values will be simple.

Comment: It is not. I open a file in a different location, and put the contents in a string. I don't know if there is a different way to go about this, but my current code is already built around it being a string

Comment: Fair play.  I've added an answer to show how the *string* can be read into a dict and parsed.

Comment: Then what format **is** it?

Comment: Wait... Are you saying **you** build that string? Why don't you build JSON then?

Comment: I don't know who built it like this, the company I work for bought this code. The original String, before it became this, was cluttered with junk. The person who wrote it removed all the junk with 20 lines of var.replace()

Comment: Hmm, who clutters their data with junk? Are you sure it was junk, not **useful** structure information? The standard answer for *"How do I parse this?"* is *"Ask the creator of the data what format it is and use a proper parser for that"*, not *"Remove everything you don't understand and try to fumble your way to a solution from there"*. Also see [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do by this way:

```
multiline_str = '''
"key0": "value0",
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
'''

lines = multiline_str.strip().split('\n')

lines = [line.rstrip(', ') for line in lines]

pairs = [line.split(': ') for line in lines]

keys = [pair[0].strip('"') for pair in pairs]
values = [pair[1].strip('"') for pair in pairs]

print(keys[0])
print(values[0])
```

Result:

```
key0
value0
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the string appears to be in rough JSON / Python dict format, the following can be used to read the keys and values into individual lists, with *minimal* string manipulation.

```
import ast  # Optional
import json

s = '''
"key0": "value0",
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2"  # <-- Trailing comma removed.
'''

# Add curly braces to the start and end of string.
s_ = f'{{{s}}}'
# Read JSON-like string into a Python dict.
d = json.loads(s_)
# Option to address trailing comma.
#d = ast.literal_eval(s_)

# Extract keys and values as lists.
keys = list(d.keys())
values = list(d.values())
```

Output:

```
>>> keys, values
(['key0', 'key1', 'key2'], ['value0', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

**Note on the trailing comma:**

If it is not possible (or tedious) to remove the trailing comma, the `ast` library can be of help.  Simply replace the `json.loads(s_)` call with `ast.literal_eval(s_)`, and the trailing comma is no longer an issue.

Comment: Why not just remove the comma with a little code?

Comment: Personally, I think its just a lingerer from the copy/paste and not really in the original dataset.  So the answer focuses on the core-problem, and not littered with superfluous code.

Answer (score 0):

By *dict* construction which will conveniently provide you with separate keys and values:

```
d = dict([map(lambda s: s.strip('"'), row.strip().split(': '))
          for row in s.split(',') if row.strip()])
print(d.keys())
print(d.values())
```

---

```
dict_keys(['key0', 'key1', 'key2'])
dict_values(['value0', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

You can convert those to lists or keep working with a dict.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a large data-set you could try `re` using [`re.finall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of traditional loops to see if that helps:

`r'"(.*?)"\s*:'` matches a quoted string followed by a colon, which represents the keys and `r':\s*"(.*?)"\s*,'` matches a colon, a quoted string and a comma which represents the values.

```py
import re

data_str = '''
"key0": "value0",
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
'''

keys = re.findall(r'"(.*?)"\s*:', data_str)
values = re.findall(r':\s*"(.*?)"\s*,', data_str)

print(keys)
print(values)
```

---

```py
['key0', 'key1', 'key2']
['value0', 'value1', 'value2']
```

You can now access individual key or value using their corresponding index:

```
print(keys[0]) # key0
print(values[0]) # value0
```